# Can Xbox 360 and PS3 players go online together in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, psn, xbox-network

My friend and I really want to play GTA 5 together but we cant figure out how.
Were friends on Rockstar Social Club so will that help?

Please answer

Answer (score 0):

Cross platform play between Xbox 360 and PS3 is not possible in GTA5

Sources: 
[Rockstar support forum](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201155743-Cross-platform-GTA-Online-Multiplayer-PLEASE-SUPPORT-)
[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GTA/comments/31srmt/gtav_is_gta_online_gonna_be_cross_platform)
Own expirience